# How to list the contents of a compressed tar file in Java

Tags: java, tar

How do I list the contents of a compressed tar file in Java without extracting the files? I have looked at apache ant api, and I can see how to extract files, but I cannot work out how to just list them. The tar files are either bz2 or gz.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I recommend using [TrueZIP](https://christian-schlichtherle.bitbucket.io/truezip/). It's *really* good.

> TrueZIP is a framework for virtual file systems and a library for accessing archive files as if they were just plain old directories.
>
> As a framework, TrueZIP provides the interfaces and classes to write file system drivers which plug-in to its federated file system space.
>
> As a library, TrueZIP provides convenient multi-threaded read/write access to archive files as if they were just plain old directories in a file system path.

It's an excellent, fast library. It has [TAR drivers](https://christian-schlichtherle.bitbucket.io/truezip/truezip-driver/truezip-driver-tar/), and [can handle `*.tar.gz` and `*.tar.bz2` files](https://christian-schlichtherle.bitbucket.io/truezip/usecases/index.html). The JavaDocs are clear and complete, though I found the standalone tutorials insufficient - I had to read the JavaDoc to get things working.

...Which brings me to the only downside I found: it might take a little while to wrap your head around TrueZIP. Initially, I had issues getting anything to work, but it "clicked" after a little while and I had no more difficulties.

Comment: Thanks, I've tried it out and it works for the most part, but there are certain tar files that seem to throw exceptions or give incorrect results. Namely tar files that contain a directory as the first entry, but without a trailing forward slash.

Comment: Links are dead.

Comment: @ImpulseTheFox thanks for the heads up. I've fixed the links, but you're always welcome to suggest an edit yourself :)

Answer (score 1):

```
TarArchiveInputStream tin = new TarArchiveInputStream(new FileInputStream(tempFile));
ArchiveEntry entry = tin.getNextEntry();
while (entry != null) {
  System.out.println("File Name " + entry.getName());//List file name
  entry = tin.getNextEntry();      
}
```