# Is there any way to create tar file without using third party libraries?

Tags: java, tar

Can we create tar file without using third party libraries?

Thanks in advance.

Regards,
Sreenath Reddy

Comment: If you can code from scratch, yes sure you can.

Comment: Tar is not part of the JRE, so you'll have to write your own tar

Comment: Why are you trying to avoid third party libraries? Is it technical limitations or legal limitations?

Comment: Also you can call tar (if it's installed) with Runtime.exec().

Comment: I think you should reword this question to ask something more specific. In the current form, you are asking if something is possible, and possible answers would be either "Yes" or "No".

Comment: Any reason not to use `jar` files?

Comment: c.f. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5320164/how-to-list-the-contents-of-a-compressed-tar-file-in-java

Answer (score 3):

There is no build-in support of the tar format in the standard library, no.

But it is possible, yes. The [Wikipedia page about tar](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tar_%28file_format%29#Format_details) has a overview description of the format, and also links to more detailed descriptions (in the External links section). You should not need more to create a tar file with Java. For convenience and performance, use a DataOutputStream on top of BufferedOutputStream and FileOutputStream (if you want to save this as a file).

Of course, using an existing tar library is less error prone, easier to use and might even be faster.